# Something like curl in Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to do something like CURL in jsp page. I need to check if website has some string in it. I am very bad in Java, that's why this is maybe stupid question, but it might be useful for someone else also.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks but you dont need to downvote because I couldn't formulate question as they did

Answer (score 2):

Check HttpClient from apache...

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Will do anything you may need.

Thanks!

@leo.

Comment: +1, HttpClient is much better than `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine for a one-off you could use Guava's Resources.readLines(URL url, Charset charset) command. If this was something you're doing on every page (:shudder:), you'd definitely want to look into apache commons' http client and use a connection pool. Though if you have a problem set that involves having to download someone else's web page before displaying your own, you're certainly going to have scaling/performance problems.

See: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Resources.html